# Trying to implement Jekyll Slideshow but unsure of syntax

Tags: javascript, markdown, jekyll

I am trying to implement https://github.com/matthewowen/jekyll-slideshow, however I am unsure of what Matt means in the documention when he says:

```
For any content that you'd like the slideshow process to work on, use the filter 'slideshows' in your template, like so:

{{ content | slideshows }}
```

I am using HTML rather than markdown. My html looks like...

```
<ul>    
<li><img src="assets/images/77_xs650.JPG" alt="Example image" title="" /></li>
<li><img src="assets/images/650_chop.JPG" alt="Example image" title="" /></li>
<li><img src="assets/images/sr500.JPG" alt="Example image" title="" /></li>
<li><img src="assets/images/triumph.jpg" alt="Example image" title="" /></li>
</ul>
```

How do I use the filter 'slideshows' on this data?

Comment: What happens if you modify the `{{ content }}` part of your page template to read `{{ content | sideshows}}` and build?

Comment: Great, i'll add it as the solution so you accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template that you want to use replace `{{ content }}` with `{{ content | sideshows}}`